# A kids' fiction book about a space explorer who sketches what he sees

Tags: story-identification, books, space-exploration

I'm looking for a kids' book with a space explorer who sketches the animals and plants he encounters. His space ship looks like a glass bubble but that's all I can remember.

Comment: Hi Emma, could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to add in more details, we're going to need a few more to find your story.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of Wayne Barlowe's [Expedition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_(book)), which is about a guy exploring a far-off planet and its wildlife.

**[About] a space explorer who sketches the animals and plants he encounters.**

> Barlowe writes as a sort of 24th century Audubon, presenting his findings in a collection of paintings, sketches, field notes, and diary entries from his explorations of Darwin IV. He details a bewildering variety of alien lifeforms...

While I couldn't find any pictures of his ship (which has a glass-walled command/observation area), here are a few of his sketches here:
[image]

While the book is a bit rare, the Discovery Channel made a documentary series called [Alien Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Planet), which talks about the plausability of Barlowe's lifeforms, as well as the practical considerations of expeditions to other worlds (Barlowe's pod is replaced with two robotic drones).